# Unable to call jQuery function in another file from .jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a java web app ive been building to learn how to use servlets and jsp's.

Im trying to put some jQuery functions into a .js file and include the file in my jsp page and call the functions, but I cannot get it to work.

Files im working with:

```
web > js > myFunctions.js
web > WEB-INF > views > _header.jsp
web > WEB-INF > views > homeview.jsp
```

Contents of `myFunction.js`:

```
function hideButtons(userSession) {
    alert("hello");

// HIDE BUTTONS WHEN NO USER IS LOGGED IN
    if (userSession === "") {
        $('#logoutBtn').hide();
        $('#productBtn').hide();
        $('#acctBtn').hide();
    }

// HIDE BUTTONS WHEN USER IS LOGGED IN
    if (userSession !== "") {
        $('#loginBtn').hide();
        $('#loginForm').hide();
    }
}
```

Contents of `_header.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/myFunctions.js"></script>

<div style="background: #E0E0E0; height: 55px; padding: 5px;">
     
    <div style="text-align: center;">

        <div id="homeBtn" style="display: inline; padding-right: 10px;">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div id="productBtn" style="display: inline; padding-right: 10px;">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/productList">Product List</a>
        </div>
        <div id="acctBtn" style="display: inline; padding-right: 10px;">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userInfo">My Account</a>
        </div>
        <div id="logoutBtn" style="display: inline; padding-right: 10px;">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        hideButtons('${loggedInUser}');

    });

</script>
```

Contents of `homeView.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Home Page </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <jsp:include page="_header.jsp"></jsp:include>

        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h3> Home Page </h3>
            Welcome to the Home Page of my sample java web application.
        </div>

        <div>
            <b>It includes the following functions:</b>
            <ul>
                <li>Login</li>
                <li>Storing user information in cookies</li>
                <li>Product List</li>
                <li>Create Product</li>
                <li>Edit Product</li>
                <li>Delete Product</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="loginForm">
            <hr>
            <jsp:include page="_login.jsp"></jsp:include>
        </div>

        <jsp:include page="_footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </body>
</html>
```

My idea was that since `_header.jsp` will be included on all of my web pages, that i will call some functions there and they will be applied to all those web pages.

If i take the jQuery out of `myFunctions.js` and place it directly into `_header.jsp` everything works just like I had planned. But for some reason I cannot call the functions inside the external .js file.

Is there something im doing wrong or missing?

**UPDATE**

Turns out I was having an issue with the path to the .js resource. 
I was giving it

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/../../js/myFunctions.js"></script>`

The `_header.jsp` page is in `WEB-INF -> views` and my `js` folder is outside `WEB-INF` so i thought that telling to go up two directories it would be able to find it.

After guessing and saying

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/myApp/js/myFunctions.js"></script>`

It found the path and loaded the resource properly.
But i am still not sure why the first way I had it is incorrect and didnt work. I have seen it done that way in applications before.

Is there some sort of mapping that im missing? Like declaring a path to the `js` folder inside the `web.xml`?

Comment: are you sure that myFunctions.js file loaded. check in browser network

Comment: @Dinesh If it wasnt loaded, how would i load it other than just including it in the .jsp file with a `<script>` tag?

Comment: that is the only option to load external js files. did check in network calls?

Comment: @Dinesh i inspected the page with Chrome dev tools and see that `myFunctions.js` failed to load. It says `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. So somehow my Tomcat server isnt loading the file?

Comment: Just load this js file into another brouser tab where you can see the js page code. If this js file loaded successfully than you can add that link to your .jsp page and that should work fine.

Comment: can you please show me the link in network calls?

Comment: Is this what youre looking for: `http://localhost:8081/js/myFunctions.js `
The app root is: `http://localhost:8081/myApp/`

Comment: your link should be http://localhost:8081/myApp/js/myFunctions.js

Comment: This localhost:8081/myApp/js/myFunctions.js is open in brouser tab ??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is because inside my Tomcat configurations for IntelliJ, I gave my application deployment a context path of `/myApp` and that was messing me up.

After removing that I was able to say `/../../js/myFunctions.js` and it found the file properly.